# Why is Wolverine's hand missing?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

In the picture below it appears that (this version of) Wolverine has only got one hand and one set of claws, the other hand seems to be missing.

What happened to his missing hand and claws? How did he lose them and how does his body react to the missing piece of Adamantium?

[image: Picture of Wolverine seemingly missing a hand]

Comment: And the real key question here: does anyone call him Stumpy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**It is an alternate version of Wolverine from the [Age of Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Apocalypse) storylines. He is called [Weapon X](http://marvel.com/universe/Weapon_X_%28Age_of_Apocalypse%29) in that universe. The Age of Apocalypse continuum briefly replaced the current Earth-616 reality but was later retconned and redubbed Earth-295.**

> In the "Age of Apocalypse" story arc, the Wolverine/Logan character is again a member of the X-Men, this time using the code-name Weapon X rather than Wolverine. In this reality the events which saw the character's Adamantium ripped out have never occurred, and it is Magneto that helps him to control his feral rages. Most significantly, Weapon X is missing a hand, cut off by Cyclops (who in turn is missing an eye thanks to Weapon X). The claws on this hand still exist, however, which appear by piercing through the metal stump covering the break. Consistent with the main characterisation, this version is also shown to be a loner, his back story presenting him as an unwilling recruit to the X-Men. He and Jean Grey are lovers in this reality.

Comment: Does the metal stump reseal itself when the claws are retracted?

Comment: Beat me too it!

Comment: Oh, so it never happened in the comic book?!

Comment: @JackBNimble Interested in that myself.

Comment: We did not get to see the fight between Prelate Cyclops and Weapon X which costs him his hand. The stories start with him missing the hand. And to be fair, despite the talented writers who were assigned to the project, it was a RAMBLING MESS. (Warren Ellis, Howard Mackie, Larry Hama, Jeph Loeb, Mark Waid)

Comment: "The claws on this hand still exist, however, which appear by piercing through the metal stump covering the break." I was referring to this, as the stump on that image is smooth, does it reseal itself when they are put away?

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing Weapon X, pop the claws on the cut off hand. He used the stump as weapon in hand to hand but released the claws. I suspect they would be less effective without the support of the hand to guide them.

Comment: @Thaddeus I need to re-read this, when AoA originally came out (summer of 95 I believe) I was a HUGE fan. Maybe I have nostalgia tainting my memory of the event. I'll pick up the omnibus one of these days.

Comment: I was a fan, but for all the wrong reasons. I loved the idea of retooling the Marvel Universe. It had gotten staid, stiff and inflexible. My problem was the apparently uncoordinated effort between what would have been the ultimate bullpen of writers. Maybe my standards are just too high. I loved the idea but I felt the execution was lacking...

Comment: @MikeBrown I think you are right about the claws, but I believe the metal cap had already been removed when he popped them out.  Not sure because, like you, I read them when they first came out but haven't reread them in a long time.

Comment: But.. but.. HOW? According to that bio he still has healing factor...

Comment: Weapon X's Earth-295 healing factor was not anywhere near as powerful as the Earth-616 version. The injury caused by Prelate Cyclops was so great, it seemed to cause a permanent injury to Weapon X. And unlike Wolverine, Weapon X, if he takes enough damage, can be killed permanently.

Comment: @Thaddeus Thanks for clearing that up (about the healing factor).

Comment: So now, Cyclops really *is* a Cyclops? Cool...

Answer (score 5):

For the question about the Stump...

Wolverine (or Weapon X) pops his claws *through* the steel stump he wears, piercing through it to kill someone when his good arm was too damaged to used. Weapon X may not have as good a healing factor, yet he does survive reentry, stabbing Elizabeth Braddoc (Magma), a fall off a high-flying airplane, a whole blister of fights, and at least two fights against two seperate Horsemen. So, no, the stump is not self-sealing, and not even a last resort; Weapon X used his claws to kill Donald Pierce, and save Brian Braddoc of the Human High Counsel.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer.